# Design pattern for Excel like workbook editor

Tags: excel, design-patterns, editor

I've been assigned to a software development task for a excel like editor. Basically the editor is working on 2-dimensional data, should have the basic editing features such as add/remove rows/columns, edit cells, undo redo etc. 
Please point me some good design patterns for this type of job, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to figure out all design patterns for a project in advance, wait until you run into a specific design issue and think about patterns that address that issue.

That being said, the features you list here do call out the likelyhood that you'll be wanting to use the [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern, so that each possible operation (add column, add row, remove column, edit cell, etc.) is supported by a command object, and enabling undo/redo for your commands with additional help from the [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Did you mean to recommend the Memento pattern for undo\redo? The Command pattern is more commonly used for the UI.

Comment: The patterns are related.  It's common to implement multiple levels of undo with Command, though one mechanism for doing this is storing the old state as a memento together with the command on the stack.  But this note is worthy of an edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context of use.

You could check out some common usage guidelines for tables here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/richclient/index.html?/webfolder/ux/middleware/richclient/guidelines5/tblInteraction.html

Very often users want an Excel-like UX for table data manipulation, including actual export to Excel. You can provide for edit, sort, add row, enlarge, etc. If the user is editing in a table try that guideline. It's intended for enterprise users, so customize accordingly.

HTH